# How understand what the space type in the text

Tags: javascript

So. I have some text with spaces. We have two types of spaces: enter(like new string), and just space between word. How to understand what type is used in the text, use only code?

Comment: You can use `indexOf` to check whether a string contains a specific character. A line break is `'\n'` and a space is `' '`.

Comment: There are actually a few different kinds of "white space".  White spaces include: space, tab, line feed, carriage return. Each has its own unique ASCII code and way of representing in your code depending upon the context. Please provide some context. Are you trying to create a regex, remove white space? Count them? What is the actual problem you would like to solve?

Comment: I`m trying to find count of line feed. I tried to found that used split('/n'), but i got nothing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank a lot @lurker, I do my task something like that: `Array.split(new RegExp(String.fromCharCode(10)))`.